# Angular 2 - Expandable table row containing another table

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm looking for a datatable which has expandable rows containing other rows (basically a table within a table).

I have found an [PrimeNG example](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowexpansion) but this only displays more information about the same row when it's expanded.  There seems to be a few AngularJS example but I can't find any for Angular 2.

This is another example of what I'm looking for on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/fdTMNTiLis), but when I use it the rows don't expand.  I have the bootstrap stylesheet imported in index.html and I'm able to use other bootstrap features.

Comment: You can add another table inside row expansion template, it is up to you what to display in expanded content. There is also row grouping http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowgroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a primeng datatable within the rowexpansion template with the value of the datatable set to a property (usually an array) of a row.

```
<ng-template let-cp pTemplate="rowexpansion">
      <p-dataTable *ngIf="cp.associated_seasons" #dtSeasons [value]="cp.associated_seasons">
      </p-dataTable>
</ng-template>
```

here "cp" is your reference to a row in the main data table and cp.associated_seasons refers to a property of the row called "associated_seasons".